# localhost:8080 displays type error "code" : "Forbidden" on any servers

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, jboss

localhost:8080 does not works, the only thing I get is

{

"type" : "error",

"code" : "Forbidden"

}

written on page.

last thing what I remember is I used webSocket using javaee-api-7.0.jar package in JBoss 7.1as . Before that it was working fine. But now neither JBoss diplays localhost nor tomcat nor glassfish.

Comment: Have you set any application as Root application (via jboss-web.xml) ?did you alter any configuration parameter in the web (as7) or undertow (wildfly) subsystem ?

Comment: Actually One of my application(RealPlayer) was interfering with port 80, I uninstalled it and now everything is working fine...

Answer (score 0):

Its sorted!.. I was trying to install XAMPP and it prompt me an error saying one of my application(RealPlayer) is not allowing to access port number(Don't remember exact statement). I removed it from my pc and now my localhost is working fine...